# How to tell Sprite Kit which function to run?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have four enemies. For every enemy I have a function that runs animation. Hero is dying if it touches an enemy. Basically, I need to say to a program: If hero touches that enemy, then run that function. If it touched another – run another function. How hard can it be, right? But I'm pulling my hair off for two days now because I can't do it. This is my ColliderType:

```
enum ColliderType:UInt32 {
    case Cookie = 1
    case Rabbit = 2
    case Mouse = 3
    case Hamster = 4
    case Cat = 5
}
```

Those are their physic bodies (it's a sample, not whole code):

```
self.cookie.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: CGFloat(self.cookie.size.width / 2))
self.cookie.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
self.cookie.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Cookie.rawValue
self.cookie.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Mouse.rawValue
self.cookie.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Mouse.rawValue

self.mouse.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.mouse.size)
self.mouse.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
self.mouse.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Mouse.rawValue
self.mouse.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Cookie.rawValue
self.mouse.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Cookie.rawValue
```

This is the one of my functions to run the animation:

```
func eatenByMouse() {
    self.groundSpeed = 0
    self.cookie.hidden = true
 let animateAction = SKAction.animateWithTextures(self.mouseArray, timePerFrame: 0.1)
    self.mouse.runAction(animateAction)
}
```

This is didBeginContact:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    dead()
}
```

And I have absolutely no idea what to store in a "dead" function. Please help me, I tried everything I know.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `contact` in `didBeginContact` method returns the appropriate information you need. You need to get the two body variables and compare their categoryBitMask and then call the method of choice for animation.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody
    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    } else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

   if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Cookie.toRaw() &&
       secondBody.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Mouse.toRaw()) {
       eatenByMouse()
   }
   if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Cookie.toRaw() &&
       secondBody.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Rabbit.toRaw()) {
       eatenByRabbit()
   }
}
```

Comment: It's strange but after implementing your code it's not stopping the ground and animation isn't running. (not doing thing that are in eatenBy... functions). Why is that?

Comment: Yes, it's definitely something wrong. It's not executing functions that are in curly braces.

Comment: I've updated the code above to solve the issues. Basically the `bodyA` and `bodyB` that are return in the variable contact of the `didBeginContact` method, are not passed in a particular order so the `if else` ensures that the  bodies are sorted by their categoryBitMask.

Answer (score 0):

Those suggestions isn't working for me. So I decided to post code that is working, for someone with similar problem:

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Mouse.rawValue || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Mouse.rawValue) {
        eatenByMouse()
    }
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Rabbit.rawValue || contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Rabbit.rawValue) {
        eatenByRabbit()
    }
```